# implementing traits for dyn Fns

Tags: rust, function-pointers, traits

Today I was playing around with function traits. Though the example I show below might not practically be very useful, I do wonder why it doesn't compile.

```rust
pub fn do_something(o: &(dyn Other + 'static)) {

}

trait Other {
    fn do_something_other(&self);
}

impl<A> Other for dyn Fn(A) {
    fn do_something_other(&self) {
        do_something(self);
    }
}
```

Here I implement a trait for a function type. This function type is generic over it's parameter. This means that if you were to do it like this:

```rust
pub fn do_something(o: &(dyn Other + 'static)) {

}

trait Other {
    fn do_something_other(&self);
}

impl<F, A> Other for F where F: (Fn(A)) + 'static {
    fn do_something_other(&self) {
        do_something(self);
    }
}
```

you get an error stating a type parameter is unconstrained.
[image: error1]

I get this and don't believe it's possible to do it with generics. But the dynamic approach, why doesn't it work? It gives the following error:

[image: error2]

I don't understand this error. It states I pass a `Fn(A) -> ()`, which doesn't implement `Other`. However, this error occurs literally *in* the implementation of `Other`. How can it not be implemented here?

My first thought was because each closure is its own type. If it has to do with this, I find the error very weird.

Comment: Why implement trait on dyn Fn while you can implement it for Fn? `impl<F> MyTrait for F where F: Fn(...)`

Comment: that's exactly what I explain in my second example in the question. You can't because that gives an "unconstrained lifetime parameter" error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first construction fails because you cannot convert a `&dyn A` into a `&dyn B`, even when implementing `B` for `dyn A`.

```
trait A {}

trait B {
    fn do_thing(&self);
}

impl B for dyn A {
    fn do_thing(&self) {
        let b: &dyn B = self;
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:25
  |
9 |         let b: &dyn B = self;
  |                ------   ^^^^ expected trait `B`, found trait `A`
  |                |
  |                expected due to this
  |
  = note: expected reference `&dyn B`
             found reference `&(dyn A + 'static)`
```

Well, you *can* convert traits but only with help from the source trait. But since in this case the source is `Fn`, that's not a route.

---

The second construction fails because Rust won't let you implement traits that can conflict. Trying to implement `B` for a type that implements `A<_>` will automatically be rejected because types can have multiple implementations of `A<_>`.

```
trait A<T> {}

trait B {
    fn do_thing(&self);
}

impl<T, U> B for T where T: A<U> {
    fn do_thing(&self) {}
}
```

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `U` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
7 | impl<T, U> B for T where T: A<U> {
  |         ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

Regarding `Fn`s in particular, its somewhat hard to tell since usually function objects only implement a single `Fn` trait. However, the keyword is *usually* since you can enable a feature on nightly to do just that. And the trait system usually doesn't play favorites.

---

So what can you do? Well the first method is still *functional*, just you have to keep the implementation within the trait. You can use the second method if you use a concrete types for the function arguments.

You can conceivably implement `Other` for `&dyn Fn(_)` (implementing it on the reference and not the object itself). But that's not particularly convenient with how `Fn` objects are usually used.

```
pub fn do_something(o: &dyn Other) {}

trait Other {
    fn do_something_other(&self);
}

impl<A> Other for &dyn Fn(A) {
    fn do_something_other(&self) {
        do_something(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // THIS WORKS
    let closure: &dyn Fn(_) = &|x: i32| println!("x: {}", x);
    closure.do_something_other();
    
    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    // let closure = |x: i32| println!("x: {}", x);
    // closure.do_something_other();
}
```

Another option would be to make the `Other` trait generic in order to constrain `A`, but that of course depends on how its designed to be used.